# IList<int> to object[]

Tags: c#

What's the simplest way to perform this transformation:

`IList<int>` to `object[]`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the simplest, but it's definitely the most efficient:

```
var result = new object[list.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    result[i] = list[i]; //Warning: Inevitable boxing happening here
```

Edit: If your list is somehow slower with indexing than with is `IEnumerable<T>` interface, then just replace the `for` loop with a `foreach` loop.

(Personally I hate `Enumerable`'s methods in areas where efficiency is even remotely concerned, simply because of how they create numerous internal objects and perform multiple inefficient passes through the data.)

Comment: Is this (wot I would have done naively) more efficient than SLaks suggestion?

Comment: Yeah, because `Enumerable.Cast<T>()` creates a new `CastIterator` object that's immediately discarded; also, SLaks's method goes through the entire array twice, whereas this method only goes through it once. Furthermore (this last reason gets into the field of microoptimization, but it's still valid) indexing an array directly is faster than indexing it through anything else (except a pointer) -- even when compared to indexing it through an `IList<T>`.

Comment: @Lambert: Why does it go through the array twice?

Comment: @Eric: Er, by the "array", I mean the list. The LINQ method goes through it twice: once for the cast, again for converting it to an array.

Comment: @Lambert: Why does it go through it once for the conversion? I'm not understanding what you're getting at here. The list is only iterated once. Think about it this way: When is the *first* item of the list accessed *from the list* for the *second* time? It isn't. The list is only accessed *once*. Where are you getting this strange idea that the data is passed over multiple times?

Comment: @Eric: Every item goes through two iterators, so effectively, every item is read twice, right?

Comment: OK, then your solution also "reads every item twice". Once to fetch the int from the list and put it in a box, and once to access the box and put it in the array. How are the two different? Every item in the list is accessed in *two* storage locations; the original location and the boxed location.

Comment: Because the array's iterator has to read the data, write it in a field, and then re-read it from the that location (for the Cast's `Current` property to work)... an extra read that might need to be avoided, if the struct is large. (I guess that would make it three reads instead of two, since there's also the read of the reference... I wasn't really counting it that closely.)

Comment: Good point. But is that the largest inefficiency? The big inefficiency is not that each item is being copied multiple times to get it into the array; that's unfortunate but inevitable. The big inefficiency is that the ToArray extension method can't do any smart optimizations on the conversion to array because the result of the cast is an enumeration of *unknown size*. In your code, the size of the final array is determined up front, so there is no need to reallocate any arrays along the way. In SLaks' suggestion, there might be several temporary arrays allocated and copied.

Comment: @Eric: Hence why the *first* reason I mentioned was the fact that the `CastIterator` object is created and discarded... aside from the extra allocation, I also implied that it's an iterator, and hence conveys no size information. I didn't actually say anything about the fact that the size is unknown, but it was exactly why I posted this answer... thanks for clarifying that though. :)

Comment: @Eric: Also... it's actually *not* necessarily a small inefficiency, since it turns an O(2n) function into O(n)... they're both technically O(n), and if your array is only ten elements long, then yeah, the extra copying is nothing compared to the extra allocations. But if your array is a few megabytes, you could definitely see a difference, so not all O(n) algorithms are created equal.

Answer (score 10):

Use LINQ:

```
object[] arr = list.Cast<object>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `List<T>.ToArray()` method. More documentation here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819.aspx

Comment: He said `IList<T>`.  Also, that won't help.

Comment: that would result in an `int[]` not an `object[]`

Answer (score -1):

`myList.ToArray< object>();`

Comment: `ToArray()` cannot be called from an `IList`

Comment: @claguardia IList<T> inherits from IEnumerable<T>, so there is a ToArray(), but only ToArray<int> and not ToArray<object>

Comment: @CodeInChaos I suppose you're right, but that still won't solve this issue, because he wants objects.